# Protection of Hogwarts against man-made, non-human devices

Tags: harry-potter

As stated multiple times beforehand, common muggles can not see/reach Hogwarts due to magical repellents. Shortly before Hogwarts also GPS and similar stuff stops working. But is there any mention (in-/out of universe) how Hogwarts is protected against man-made stuff such as a large bomb or nuke?
I was just imagining: A muggle relative is angry at the wizards while knowing them. In order to hurt them, he plants a GPS-device to a wizard attending the school. He knows that he will not get the exact place, but every place in an area around ~10 km should be enough to direct a nuke onto it. He does not care, if he hits the school, because the blast will do the rest. After it drops outside of the protection field preventing electronic devices, it will go off. For the largest Czar-bomba that is definitely enough.
The muggle even can increase the accuracy by determining the protection radius, and then send something in the middle.
Thus: Are there any protections against situations like that?

Comment: It is unknown, unless you want to go read the various fanfics about "Muggles kick wizard butt."

Comment: @pleurocoelus I've never been interested in Harry Potter, but I kind of want to read one of those fanfics now.

Comment: Some random muggle relative has the capability to launch nuclear strikes on Scotland?

Comment: If the random muggle relative is a high-ranking military, why not? (Dr. Strangelove...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Nope. At least there doesn't appear to be any evidence of any such protections. Why would there be?

The protections we know of include many of the ones that you mention in the question.

- Muggles cannot physically see Hogwarts. If they come near it they just see a ruin and a 'keep out' sign.
- Hogwarts is unplottable. It won't appear on Google Maps or any form of atlas or street map.
- Electronic devices don't function properly in the vicinity of Hogwarts due to all the magic.
- Hogwarts is pretty much in the middle of nowhere (as is implied by the amount of time it takes to travel there from London and the fact that it has an exclusively magical village just down the road. The Ministry would make sure that there were no Muggle dwellings nearby).
- There were some additional protective charms placed on it during *Half-Blood Prince* but these were basically only there to prevent an invasion of Death Eaters.

A number of questions present themselves in relation to your theoretical Muggle friend.

**How did he get his hands on nuclear weapons?** I mean, really. He'd surely be on the radar of the Muggle authorities (perhaps in more ways than one...).

**How does he know about Hogwarts?** Even if he lived nearby (and, as I say, I think it's unlikely that the Ministry allowed Muggles to live in the vicinity of Hogwarts), how would he come to know of Hogwarts? He can't see it. Any revelation of magic - by a stray student on a Hogsmeade outing, for instance - would be dealt with by the Ministry anyway. He'd be Obliviated immediately in line with standard procedure. If he were related to a wizard then he *may* know of Hogwarts, depending on how closely related he were. The Dursleys clearly know *of* Hogwarts but their knowledge doesn't stretch much further than 'there's a magical school somewhere that our relative goes to'. I'm sure the Ministry deems the risk that a relative of a Hogwarts student is a wannabe mass murderer is (very, very) low.

**Why would those people who realistically *do* have nuclear weapons attack Hogwarts?** The Ministry of Magic maintains good relations with their Muggle counterparts. There would be no reason for the Muggle government to launch an unprovoked attack on a school in any case.

**Why would the Ministry take any steps to prevent this circumstance from happening?** As I say, the Ministry wouldn't be expecting any sort of attack from any Muggle. They certainly wouldn't expect an attack from a lone Muggle, nuclear or otherwise. Add in the natural sense of wizarding superiority (aka arrogance) and you'll quickly see why the wizarding community wouldn't believe that Muggles are capable of causing them any real harm.

> There is another reason for most wizards' avoidance of Muggle devices, and that is cultural. The magical community prides itself on the fact that it does not need the many (admittedly ingenious) devices that Muggles have created to enable them to do what can be so easily done by magic. To fill one's house with tumble dryers and telephones would be seen as an admission of magical inadequacy.
>    <sub>[*Technology* (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology)</sub>

So, yes, assuming this one-in-a-gazillion circumstance presented itself, there's no reason why the Muggle wouldn't be able to drop the payload.

Comment: It strikes me that a few minutes after finding out about the wizarding world, the Muggle presidents of the world would launch a nuclear strike on the ten wizarding schools.

Comment: @Valorum. I'm not sure that that would relieve the sense of paranoia that they'd be feeling in that moment. It may also not do their poll numbers much good.

Comment: Bomb first, ask questions later. Tell the media you're proactive in protecting the common man.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Pfft. Nuclear accidents aren't common, but at least all ten of these bombs went off in the middle of nowhere, away from densely  populated areas. In fact, most seemed to be centred on old ruined castles

Comment: @Valorum This is why Durmstrang keeps its location secret, isn't it?

Comment: I'd say "Electronic devises don't function properly in the vicinity of Hogwarts due to all the magic." would prevent a nuclear strike. There are some fairly fancy gadgets that run those things.

Comment: @Sidney - Nukes have a pretty solid range. If the first one failed, you'd [dial up the size and try a mile out](http://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/?&kt=1200&lat=57.4306192&lng=-4.6515618&hob_opt=1&hob_psi=5&hob_ft=10887&ff=50&zm=9)

Comment: @Valorum Ah, I was looking in terms of the Little boy fireball which was .1 km. Still pretty sizable, but not nearly the 10 km the tsar bomba reaches.

Comment: @valorum - I'm reasonably certain that if you waterboard enough current/former Durmstrang students, at least one of them would spill the beans on the approximate location of the school

Comment: Nothing like a bit of lighthearted speculation eh?

Comment: What makes you think Hogwarts is unplottable? The books make it pretty clear that it's plottable.

Comment: @ibid They do? Where? I recall the books saying Hogwarts *was* Unplottable, though I'll admit I don't have a citation handy.

Comment: @JoeWhite - A) In GoF Hermione mentions unplottability as something that non-Hogwarts schools would do. B) In HBP the Room of Requirement's absence from the Marauder's Map leads to speculation that *that room* is unplottable.

Comment: Admittedly, I typed that without doing a full canon sweep on plottability (if that's a word). I've always assumed it is unplottable. True, there's no definitive confirmation. But if Durmstrang and Beauxbatons have it then Hogwarts quite possibly does. Hogwarts cares less about guarding its magical secrets. Yet it does value anti-Muggle security. I'd interpret the unplottable factor as being part of Hogwarts being, as Hermione puts it, "hidden".  There's no firm proof, though.